# Input stream not found at : fonts.xml for JasperReports

Tags: maven, jasper-reports

I've allready two days tring to resolve this issue and no success.This exception is thrown

```
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRRuntimeException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Input stream not found at : fonts.xml
        at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fonts.SimpleFontExtensionHelper.loadFontFamilies(SimpleFontExtensionHelper.java:188)
```

I use java 8 with Maven builder

It's my pom.xml configuration

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>net.sf.jasperreports</groupId>
    <artifactId>jasperreports-fonts</artifactId>
    <version>6.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```

This is a jasperreports_extension.properties configuration which is after packaging with maven located in root path

```
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.registry.factory.system.font.families=net.sf.dynamicreports.jasper.base.JasperSystemFontExtensionsRegistryFactor
net.sf.jasperreports.extension.system.font.families.drfonts=fonts.xml
```

This is my fonts.xml

```
<fontFamily name="SansSerif">
    <exportFonts>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif</export>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>

<fontFamily name="Serif">
    <exportFonts>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'Times New Roman', Times, serif</export>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>

<fontFamily name="Monospaced">
    <exportFonts>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.html">'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
        <export key="net.sf.jasperreports.xhtml">'Courier New', Courier, monospace</export>
    </exportFonts>
</fontFamily>
```

When i do this in eclipse everthing works fine and PDF is created.

When i build via maven and try to execute from cmd then i got this exception.

I also tried to add another customfont.xml in net.sf.jasperreports.fonts and repath net.sf.jasperreports.extension.system.font.families.drfonts=fonts.xml to

net.sf.jasperreports.extension.system.font.families.drfonts=net/sf/jasperreports/fonts but nothing works....